# jq 1.5 print items from array that is inside another array

Tags: json, jq

Incoming json file contains json array per row eg:

```
["a100","a101","a102","a103","a104","a105","a106","a107","a108"]
["a100","a102","a103","a106","a107","a108"]
["a100","a99"]
["a107","a108"]
```

a "filter array" would be `["a99","a101","a108"]` so I can `slurpfile` it

Trying to figure out how to print only values that are inside "filter array", eg the output:

```
["a101","a108"]
["a108"]
["a99"]
["a108"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can port `IN` function from jq 1.6 to 1.5 and use:

```
def IN(s): any(s == .; .);
map(select(IN($filter_array[])))
```

Or even shorter:

```
map(select(any($filter_array[]==.;.)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing some simpler solution, but the following works :

```
map(select(. as $in | ["a99","a101","a108"] | contains([$in])))
```

Replace the `["a99","a101","a108"]` hardcoded array by your slurped variable.

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/hQ3ziN5WH8) !

Comment: That works great, thank you. My input has changed slightly to 
{ "input" : { "a100":1,"a101":5,"a102":7,"a103":1,"a104":1,"a105":3,"a106":3,"a107":3,"a108":11 }, ....}
How come this does not work: 
'map(select((.input|keys) as $in | $rolls | contains([$in]))) ?

https://jqplay.org/s/KuLDMePXqT

Comment: @Pavel you can use `.input|keys | map(select( . as $in | ["a99","a101","a108"] | contains([$in])))`. That said, [oguzismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56172694/1678362) is the simpler solution I was missing, I recommend using it.

Answer (score 1):

In the example, the arrays in the input stream are sorted (in jq's `sort` order), so it is worth noting that in such cases, a more efficient solution is possible using the `bsearch` built-in, or perhaps even better, the definition of `intersection/2` given at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set#Finite_Sets_of_JSON_Entities

For ease of reference, here it is:

```
def intersection($A;$B):
  def pop:
    .[0] as $i
    | .[1] as $j
    | if $i == ($A|length) or $j == ($B|length) then empty
      elif $A[$i] == $B[$j] then $A[$i], ([$i+1, $j+1] | pop)
      elif $A[$i] <  $B[$j] then [$i+1, $j] | pop
      else [$i, $j+1] | pop
      end;
  [[0,0] | pop];
```

Assuming a jq invocation such as:

```
jq -c --argjson filter '["a99","a101","a108"]' -f intersections.jq input.json
```

an appropriate filter would be:

```
($filter | sort) as $sorted
| intersection(.; $sorted)
```

(Of course if $filter is already presented in jq's sort order, then the initial sort can be skipped, or replaced by a check.)

### Output

```
["a101","a108"]
["a108"]
["a99"]
["a108"]
```

### Unsorted arrays

In practice, jq's builtin `sort` filter is usually so fast that it might be worthwhile simply sorting the arrays in order to use `intersection` as defined above.